Fast packages for solving $A x \leqslant b$, or $Ax = b$ s.t. $x_I \geqslant 0$ and $I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ be a squared matrix, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an $n$-dimensional vector. I am looking for some fast package for solving either:

$A x \leqslant b$; or
$A x = b$ for $x_{I} \geqslant 0$ and $I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$ (for the slack variables).

What would be some fast packages for this purpose?

do you have any particular programming language in mind?

@Sune thanks. Anything compatible with fortran >= 90.

Related: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404724744081-Create-models-with-FORTRAN-and-Gurobi

Thank you so much.

It's possible to call C functions from Fortran. You might practice that by getting the ECOS solver integrated. Were you looking for open-source solutions or commercial solutions?

You can try this one: https://github.com/jacobwilliams/slsqp

Thank you su much.
